# Audio data byte array volume adjustment java

Tags: java

I am doing a volume control for my wifi speaker. I need to process the raw PCM data byte array to adjust volume. But my code give me lots of noise.
follow is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i+=2) {
short audioSample = (short) (((split[i+1] & 0xff) << 8) | (split[i] & 0xff));
audioSample = (short) (audioSample * 1 * equal.vol);
split[i] = (byte) audioSample;
split[i+1] = (byte) (audioSample >> 8);
}
```

split is raw data byte array

My audio profile:
22.05K sample rate, 16 bits per sample

Comment: What is the type of `equal.vol`? Are you sure the data is in little endian format? Are you sure 0 <= `equal.vol` <= 1?

Comment: equal.vol is integer. its value from 0 to 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that `equal.vol` is declared as a floating-point type such as `float` or `double`.
2. Make sure your sample data is, in fact, little endian.
3. Make sure that 0 <= `equal.vol` <= 1; that is, make sure you're only attenuating and not amplifying.  If you want to amplify, you'll need to clamp the result of the multiplication to fit within the sample range, i.e., -32768 to +32767.  But, your sound may experience clipping when amplified in such a manner.

Comment: Still has noise. really weird